# Is there a way to in PHP to generate a unique id for members incrementing from the database?

Tags: php

I want developing a system in php. the system is for capturing information for members, so i want each member to have unique id in this form for example EXE0987.what i want is that when the form for adding new member is loaded the section for member ID is automatically filled, the ID has to be calculated from the database that is when the last largest MemberID in database was EXE0987, when the form load the memberID for new member is EXE0988. My challenge is can i make that in php

Comment: What everybody does in this situation is to let the DB handle it. Not sure if that's unfeasible for you or you're just not aware of the possibility.

Comment: In your database (I normally use mysql) add to your table a `id` column which has `auto_increment` turned on

Comment: *"My challenge is can i make that in php"* - depends on what you mean by *make*... I'd suggest just prefixing an auto-incremented id (primary key) from the *member* table in the database with the string "EXE" - you can do that easily enough with PHP.

Comment: Just use the database's auto-increment functionality. That'll give you a unique numeric ID for every record. If you need it formatted per the question, you can do that when you display it.

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is always EXE followed by a 4 digit sequential number then your best bet would be to take advantage of the auto-incrementing ID for records in your DB (assuming your DB is SQL based?)

That way the DB manages the IDs in the table and ensures uniqueness and sequence.

You can then format your ID when you model your user prefixing EXE and using `str_pad` to add your leading 0s

```
str_pad($id, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

If you're using Laravel this can be done on the `User` model using a mutator.

```
getAttributeId($value)
{
    return 'EXE' . str_pad($value, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

You could look to do something similar with whatever framework and/or models you're using.

Comment: Technically, if you're using MySQL, you could just use [ZEROFILL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) on the auto-incremented primary key (id) and avoid `str_pad` altogether.